# Nginx lots of 'hanging' / pending requests on Windows

Tags: windows, nginx

The config works fine when on a Linux server, but when on Windows, it randomly hangs -- like 50% of the time the pages will load, else it will be in a pending state for over a minute. (pending request can be seen in chrome developer tool

```
#user  nobody;
worker_processes  1;
#pid        logs/nginx.pid;
events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name 127.0.0.1;

    location / {
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:9090;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
    }

    location ~ /(lang|js|css|pic|uploads) {
        root "C:/Users/Dan/Desktop/Projects/FF_Main/public";
    }
}
```

I tried Nginx 1.7 and 1.6.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Removing the line `proxy_set_header Host $host;` fixed the issue.

Comment: any idea why it fixed?

Comment: It is really annoying to me, but this has fixed the same issue for me.